# AngularJS Jasmine Unit Tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, angularjs, jasmine

I have the following unit tests, and for some reason the second test makes other tests fail.

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, _$httpBackend_, $controller, $location, mockedResource) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    locationService = $location;

    ctrlDependencies = {
        $scope: scope, 
        resource: mockedResource,
    }

    var ctrl = $controller('myController', ctrlDependencies);
}));

it('should redirect to a new page', function() {
    scope.pageRedirectFunction();
    expect(locationService.path()).toBe('/newpage')
});

it('should delete an epic resource', function() {
    httpBackend.expectGET('/api/v1/epic/1').respond({});
    httpBackend.expectDELETE('/api/v1/epic/1').respond({});

    // Run the deletion function
    scope.deleteEpicResource()

    httpBackend.flush() // This line seems to be the rebelious one

    expect(scope.epicResources.length).toEqual(0)
})
```

I have managed to figure out the line that seems to cause the errors, and it's the `httpBackend.flush()` line. Why is the flush function causing strange behaviour?

The actual error I get from running the command `karma start` in the terminal, is:

```
 Delaying execution, these browsers are not ready: Chrome 29.0 ....
```

after a little while, the Chrome session then crashes.

Comment: What error did you got? Without that no one can even guess about it.

Comment: Of course! What a terrible mistake. Updating with the error now...

Comment: Try to increase Karma's log level to debug, to see what happens.

Comment: Just because you see an error in .flush() doesn't mean it's the problem.  What about deleteEpicResource()?  What about your test setup?  Does this happen with other browsers?

Comment: Try to use whenGET, whenDELETE, whenWHATEVER methods instead, that might work. if you're using angular-unstable, you might want to call rootScope.$digest() (dunno why but it solved some of my problems...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little-known tip about testing/mocking async requests with jasmine and AngularJS:

If you're not explicitly calling the request in your test (i.e. calling it through another function), the request won't be digested by Angular, so it makes it seem as if the request never fired (when you call `flush()`)

Try running `scope.$digest()` before your `httpBackend.flush()` call, that may do the trick.  See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/BXtFWLtKrGM/3wPUEIbjjFAJ) for more information.

Comment: I fixed this a while back, but didn't remember how I fixed it. Upon reading your response I realised that I wasn't calling flush() for all the requests I needed to. This was mostly a problem because there were API requests being loaded as soon as my controller was loaded, but I had forgotten about them.

Comment: Does adding $digest() address the concern about Chrome crashing?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have angular-mocks.js included before your tests? Also, you may want to try to load ngMocks module:

```
beforeEach(module("ngMock"));
```